# Overwriting number in binary file - C++

Tags: c++

I have a binary file where the structure counter is stored first, then the structures themselves. After adding the structure, the counter should be incremented. Code (elemCount is counter):

```
fileTemp.open(fileName, ios::binary);
fileTemp.seekg(0, ios::beg);
fileTemp.read((char*)&elemCount, sizeof(int));
elemCount += 1;
fileTemp.close();
file.open(fileName, ios::binary|ios::app);
file.seekp(0, ios::beg);
file.write((char*)&elemCount, sizeof(int));
file.close();
```

But it looks like it just writes the new counter value to the end, which is not provided.

Comment: needs a minimal complete example,sample input, desired output, and current output with a specific explanation of the problem/difference.

Comment: I guess that's what `ios::app` means (append).

Comment: Please explain your use of `ios::app` to your nearest rubber duck.

Comment: please provide minimal example with input & expected output